# How to make 'this' into std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

In the following code how do I return the same object from the `Object::get` function below. Please look at the comments in that function.

The function returns a `std::unique_ptr` of new `Object` with the given `id`. But if the `id` is the same as the object's `id` or if the object's `id` was set to `error`, then the `this` pointer(i.e. the same object) should be returned. So how do I return the same object from the `Object::get` function?

```
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class IObject
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IObject> get(std::string id) = 0;
    virtual void fun() = 0;

    virtual ~IObject() {}
};

class Object : virtual public IObject
{
public:
    Object(std::string id) : id_(id) {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<IObject> get(std::string i)
    {
        if((id() == i) || (id() == "error")) {
            // Return the same object
            //return this; // How to achieve this? How to return the same object?
            return std::make_unique<Object>(id()); // This does not return the same object.
        }

        if(ids.end() == ids.find(i)) {
            return std::make_unique<Object>("error");
        }

        return std::make_unique<Object>(i);
    }

    virtual void fun()
    {
        std::cout << "Object is: " << id() << std::endl;
    }

    std::string const& id() const
    {
        return id_;
    }

private:
    static std::set<std::string> const ids;

    std::string id_;
};

std::set<std::string> const Object::ids{"id0", "id1", "id2", "id3"};


int main()
{
    auto o = std::make_unique<Object>("id0");
    o->get("id1")->get("id2")->get("id3")->fun();
    o->get("id1")->get("idN")->get("id2")->fun();
    o->get("id1")->get("idN")->get("id2")->get("id3")->fun();
    o->get("id1")->get("id2")->get("id2")->fun();
    o->get("id1")->get("id2")->get("id2")->get("id3")->fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is *ridiculously* unsafe, to the point where I'd say you just *can't*. Are you sure you shouldn't be using `std::shared_ptr`? In that case, take a look at [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). I think you might need to refactor `Object`, so that you have one class that holds the actual data (the `std::string`) and another class that holds a pointer to the other class.

Comment: You can't change the ownership of `*this` - its creator decides what it should be. You need to redesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is straightforward.

```
    return std::unique_ptr<Object>(this);
```

However, as Nicol pointed out in his answer, this is almost certainly NOT what you want.

Consider the following code:

```
Object foo("foo");
foo.get();
```

Boom!  You've just called `free` on some memory that was not allocated on the heap

Answer (score 0):

A `unique_ptr` represents unique ownership of an object. The type is designed such that there is exactly and only one `unique_ptr` that manages the lifetime of this object; that's why it's called "unique".

Therefore, if someone already has unique ownership over the `this` object, you cannot give *someone else* unique ownership of it. Because then it wouldn't be *unique* ownership. You can't even give the current owner unique ownership of `this` because then they'd be owning it in two places.

What you want is not a reasonable thing to do. You either intend to have shared ownership semantics (and thus should use `shared_ptr` or some equivalent, which has `enable_shared_from_this`) or you don't want the function to return a `unique_ptr`.